# Problem importing GreenDroid

Tags: java, android, eclipse, buildpath, greendroid

I'm trying to import and run the GreenDroid project: https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid

But get the following error:

```
The type java.lang.Enum cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  ActionBarItem.java  /GreenDroid/GreenDroid/src/greendroid/widget    line 1  Java Problem
```

Not sure how to resolve. IDE is saying it is a build path issue.

Comment: Try going to the error, and hovering over it, sometimes it will give you an easy fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the IDE, is Java compiler set to Java 1.5 or above? Enums won't work if the compiler is set to 1.3.

In Eclipse, the setting is under Build Path/Java Compiler/JDK Compliance.

Comment: im using 1.6, any other ideas?

Comment: java.lang.Enum is part of rt.jar. JRE is not connected / wrong JRE is connected to the project?